# DVDRom full of JPGs locks XP indefinitely

Tags: windows-xp, dvd, cache, thumbnails

I have a DVD filled with about 3.5GB of large picture files (jpgs about 4mb each).

Every time I insert this disc into my computer and select the drive from explorer, it will lock up the explorer indefinitely.

I realise that it's trying to browse the whole DVD and is probably trying to generate thumbnails, so I turned off 'Cache Thumbnails' and also removed 
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\ShellImagePreview`

Windows cannot seem to leave this DVD alone so that I can use the files. It is determined to read them all before I can do anything! Arrg!

How can I access my pictures using XP? Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

Try holding down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key while it is about-to and just reading the DVD.

If that works for you, explore methods of permanently [turning off Auto-Run](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/show/article03-018), if you get tired of having to hold down that key.

Comment: Also, you can view it in "Details" viewing to prevent the thumbnails from being created.  Just use Explorer. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like, you can use the xcopy program from the command prompt to copy all of the files onto your hard-drive, where Windows can seek and generate thumbnails *much* more quickly than reading each one individually from the DVD.

Answer (score 2):

not the cure for the problem at hand, but a workaround that will get you to access your pictures:

use [UltraExplorer](http://www.mustangpeak.net/ultraexplorer.html) instead of Windows Explorer. grab the portable version and you don't even have to install the program.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem with 8gb dvd full of jpgs. It may be your AV program scanning for viruses, etc try turning it off - worked for me.